# Vagrant Phalcon variable $PTOOLSPATH is outdated

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, phalcon

I'm installing the Phalcon Vagrant box through the official github documentation but I always stumble upon the same message:

```
vagrant@phalcon:/vagrant/www$ phalcon commands help

Your environment variable $PTOOLSPATH is outdated!
Current value: /opt/phalcon-tools
New value: /usr/bin
Exit.
```

Link to guide: [Vagrant Phalcon Instructions](https://github.com/phalcon/vagrant)

Why am I getting this error message? 
This message prevents me from using the Phalcon dev-tools.

Things I've tried:

- Re-install vagrant box
- Update Vagrant to latest version
- Update VirtualBox to latest version

Information about my system and software:

- Vagrant 1.9.1
- VirtualBox 5.1.12 r112440 (Qt5.6.2)
- Windows 10 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT: This has been fixed in this commit: [link to github commit](https://github.com/phalcon/vagrant/commit/d12c028920126a373978f22f7b6cfac82101ae14)]**

The offical repository contains a bug that linked to the wrong file when using "phalcon commands".

The issue can be solved by editing the init.sh file in the cloned repository and changing `ln -s /opt/phalcon-tools/phalcon.sh /usr/bin/phalcon` to `ln -s /opt/phalcon-tools/phalcon.php /usr/bin/phalcon`

I also added `chmod ugo+x /usr/bin/phalcon` after this line (just to be sure). And behold it works now!

Keep in mind, for ease of use these changes need to be addressed before doing "vagrant up".

Comment: Use this inside vagrant in case the above solution do not work: `sudo ln -s -f /opt/phalcon-tools/phalcon.php /usr/bin/phalcon`